# Width of sprite is smaller then sprite itself when scaling

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite, scale

When I change scale the `spritenode` becomes smaller but also it's width. In the image below I have set its scale on 0.8. The red dot is the width of the sprite.

[image]

I have tried scaling with `[sprite setScale]` method and using xScale and yScale. How can the width be smaller then the sprite when scaling?

Comment: What are you using to get the width

Comment: I am calling size.width

Comment: are you sure you are not calling frame.size.width?  otherwise I am not sure what you mean by width of sprite is smaller.  when scaling your sprite, your size changes,  so if your sprite is 10x10, and you scale to .8, his size will become 8x8.  When you use frame.size.width, it does not take into account the transparent space, so will return an even smaller number

Comment: I see. When I change scale to 5 the red dot (indicated the size.width of sprite) is set to the middle of sprite. I want to scale the sprite and have the red dot on the right edge of the screen. So sprite.size.width is really the width of the sprite.

Comment: I am confused.  Is the road the sprite you are scaling?

Comment: Well then what you are doing will not work,  You are plotting the red dot at (size.width,random #),  this will anchor off of the bottom left, and show exactly where it should be on the screen.  However your sprite is drawn at bottom left anchor to the screen, but when you scale, you scale based on the sprite anchor.  So the sprite will draw on the left and right.  If you want to draw your dot on the right side of the sprite, you are going to have to do dot = (sprite.position.x  + sprite.size.width / 2)

Comment: Aha, that make sense. Indeed it's anchorpoint is on the bottomleft. But I don't understand the last part. Because when I set dot on (sprite.position.x + sprite.size.width /2) it's set on the middle of the sprite. However it's working with scale on 5 and (sprite.position.x + sprite.size.width * 2), but I prefer scale 8. And best would be flexible..

Comment: did you change your sprites anchor point?  because sprite.position.x should be the center,  if you changed your sprites anchor point to be (0,0) then you need to do position + width not width / 2

Comment: Yes, it's anchorpoint is 0.0 and scale is 8. Unfortunately the position of the dot is not right yet. When I do position + width the dot is positioned at +/- 80% of the road sprite. And when I set anchorpoint to 0.5 and position + width / 2 it's dot is positioned on +/- 130% of the road sprite.

Comment: what is your output saying?  Is your sprite even scaling

Comment: is the dot attached to the scene or to the sprite

Comment: Yes, the sprite is scaling just fine. The dot is attached to the sprite.

Comment: well thats why,  if its attached to the sprite then you need it at the width * (1 / scale factor)  this is because the dot is drawn before your sprite is scaled

Comment: Hero! That did the trick! Thanks a lot!